# Assume $Y$ is a linear subspace of X, such that Y is dense in X, and $\phi \in X^*$ such that $\phi(y)=0$ for every $y\in Y$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

I am not too sure how to do this question. I know that $Y$ is dense in $X$ if the closure of $Y$ (intersection of all closed sets in X that contain Y). However, I cannot seem to make the intuitive leaps required to answer this question. There is a similar question that uses the Hahn-Banach theorem, but this is not part of my course. So I would prefer another way of doing it!

Assume $Y$ is a linear subspace of X, such that Y is dense in X, and $\phi \in X^*$ such that $\phi(y)=0$ for every $y\in Y$. Prove $\phi(x)=0$ for every $x \in X$.

Comment: Can you say if $\phi$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes $phi$ is continuous across Y isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another proof:  Fix $x\in X$.  Since $Y$ is dense, we can find a sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $Y$ convergent to $x$.  Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $n\in N$ such that $\|x-y_n\|<\varepsilon$. Then we have 
$$|\phi(x)|=|\phi(x-y_n)|\leq\|\phi\|\|x-y_n\|<\|\phi\|\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have $\phi(x)=0$, and since $x\in X$ was arbitrary we have $\phi=0$.

Comment: thank you so much! That is a lot clearer. :_

Comment: You're welcome.  This proof only works for Banach spaces (or normed spaces), while Tsemo's proof works in the more general topological vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $X^*$ is the set of continuous linear functions on $X$. The subset of $X$ defined by $C=\{x:\phi(x)=0\}$ is closed since $\phi$ is continue, since it contains $Y$ it contains its adherence $X$.

Comment: What is the definition of adherence?

Comment: it is the smallest subset that contains $Y$

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: If $\phi$ is continue, $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is a closed subset of $X$ which contains $Y$ (and its adherence), since $Y$ is dense it is $X$.